# How to tell the state of a service from the registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, services

Lets say for example I wanted to find out what state my bluetooth service is in from the registry:

1. I'd open the registry using `regedit`
2. Find the path: `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT`

How could I tell if the bluetooth service is either, maunal, disabled, or enabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via the registry you won't be able to tell what state a service is currently in, only it's start-up mode setting (manual, automatic, disabled, etc.).    This will be held in a key named "Start" within the service's branch in the registry.

Possible values:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Value |                                                           Description                                                            |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     0 | Boot: Loaded by kernel loader. Components of the driver stack for the boot (startup) volume must be loaded by the kernel loader. |
|     1 | System: Loaded by I/O subsystem. Specifies that the driver is loaded at kernel initialization.                                   |
|     2 | Automatic: Loaded by Service Control Manager. Specifies that the service is loaded or started automatically.                     |
|     3 | Manual: The service does not start until the user starts it manually, such as by using Services or Devices in Control Panel.     |
|     4 | Disabled: Specifies that the service should not be started.                                                                      |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you're looking to get the *current* status of a service, consider using the [`sc` command](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html), or [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394602(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: This is perfect what I'm trying to do is query the registry for info, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Start Type is stored in the `Start` key

The possible values are:

- 0 - Boot
- 1 - System
- 2 - Automatic
- 3 - Manual
- 4 - Disabled